# How do I use IndexOf and Substring to list words that start with vowels in a sentence. (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, substring, indexof

I've tried to use different things to print out the vowels in the given sentence.I could not figure it out.

Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

// Then if the user write(" She is a cat but she eats onion")
// The output should be 
is
a
eats
onion

Comment: Hello Lone, provide your code trials and outputs so people can guide you

Comment: What do you mean by that, Outputs as in what I want in the Output?

Comment: the output of the code you have tried .. and your required output

Comment: You mean "An ugly cat sleeps in the sofa" => List out ["An", "ugly", "in"] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vowel letters is u,e,o,a,i and just split the sentence to the words and loop it over to check, no need to use substring or indexof

```
    public static void MainFunc()
    {
        string sentence = "An ugly cat sleeps in the sofa";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(';', ShowVowelWords(sentence)));
    }

    static char[] VOWELS = new char[] { 'u', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'i' };

    public static IEnumerable<string> ShowVowelWords(string sentence)
    {
        foreach (var word in sentence.ToLower().Split(' '))
            foreach (var c in VOWELS)
                if (word.StartsWith(c))
                    yield return word;
    }
```

[image]

**Update**

For using only indexof and substring, it would be longer to solve

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ShowVowelWords2(string input)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            int k = input.IndexOf(' ', i);
            var str = (k != -1) ? input.Substring(i, k - i) : input.Substring(i);
            i = k + 1;

            foreach (var c in VOWELS)
                if (str[0] == c)
                {
                    yield return str;
                    break;
                }

            if (k == -1)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Let `i` is index of `input`, start from zero

Let `k` getting the first index space to get the word end. Start from `i`

Let `str` to be a word which is result from substring. If `k` could get the position (aka != -1), then cut the input with started `i` and length `k-1`. Otherwise when `k=-1`, the `str` would get until end of sentence (aka last word of the sentence)

Update new `i=k+1` because of ignoring the space

Loop until get the right vowels

`k==-1` mean it in the last word, no more to go so stopping it.

Result with string `An ugly cat sleeps in the sofa and beside umbrella`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that but I have to use Substring and IndexOf because it is a school assignment.

Comment: @LoneWolf I updated my answer. I would be appreciated that you could leave upvote and accepted for your school assignment : )

Comment: Thank you for that and I'll make sure to upvote.